# How many spheres of radius $R/2$ can be packed into a can having depth $R$, height $H$, with a hemispherical top

Tags: geometry, volume

The hemispherical "cap" is on the top of the cylindrical can. So, in the side view, the total height of the container will be $R+H$.

Comment: When you say "box", do you actually mean "can" or "drum" (i.e. a container that looks circular when viewed from above)? Also, the curved top of the container is a hemisphere, rather than a semi-circle, isn't it? If my assumptions are correct, please change the question.

Comment: @bubba:yes you are right

Comment: @bubba:any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Each "layer" of spheres within the cylindrical part of the can will have two spheres, obviously. The hard part is figuring out how many speheres will fit in the cap part. This depends on the relation between $R$ and $H$.

Comment: You say "depth $R$, height $H$. What's the difference between height and depth. You should draw a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N$ be the number of spheres one can pack into the can.

As a function of $H$, it is not hard to see:

- when $0 \le H < \frac{R}{2}$, the can can hold only 1 sphere $\implies N = 1$.
- when we increase $H$ to $\frac{R}{2}$, we can start to put 2 spheres at the bottom of can
  $\implies N = 2$.
  For this $H$, there are some free spaces between these two spheres and the hemisphere   cap. However, it is not large enough to hold another sphere.
- if we further increase $H$ by an amount $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}R$, i.e. when $H$ becomes $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}R$, the free space becomes large enough to hold another sphere $\implies N = 2 + 1 = 3$.
- when we further increase $H$ to $(\frac12 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})R$, there
  are enough space in the base cylinder part of the can to put another layer of spheres 
  there. The center of spheres in these two layers form a regular tetrahedron
  of side $R$. The free space above the spheres get reduced, no longer able to hold the extra sphere. As a result, $N = 3 + 2 - 1 = 4$.

If we keep on increasing $H$, these pattern will repeat at

$$H = \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{n-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)R \quad\text{ and }\quad \left( \frac12 + \frac{n}{\sqrt{2}} \right)R$$

for every positive integer n. So the general formula for $N$ when $H \ge \frac{R}{2}$ is:

$$N = 1 + \left\lfloor 1 + \sqrt{2}( \frac{H}{R} - \frac12 )\right\rfloor
        + \left\lfloor 1 + \sqrt{2}( \frac{H}{R} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} )\right\rfloor$$

Below is an illustration of the arrangement of 7 spheres when $\displaystyle H = 
(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}})R \sim 2.28 R$.
[image: Spheres in a can]